# no matching function for call to, how to fix it?

Tags: c++

```
int main() 
{ 
    map<string, int> M; 
    vector<string> V; 
    set<string> S; 

    ifstream inFile("sample_doc.txt"); 
    copy( istream_iterator<string>(inFile), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(V) ); 
    ifstream inFile2("stopwords.txt"); 
    copy( istream_iterator<string>(inFile2), istream_iterator<string>(), inserter( S, S.begin() ) ); 

    for_each( V.begin(), V.end(), [&](string & s){ S.count(s) == 0 ? M[s]++ : true; } );
}
```

in the for_each statement, when I pass in the lambda function above, it gives me the following error.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘for_each(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, main()::__lambda0)’
   for_each( V.begin(), V.end(), [&](string & s){ S.count(s) == 0 ? M[s]++ : true; } );
```

can someone tell me how to fix it? thanks a lot.

Comment: Include the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: hi, I did include <algorithm>

Comment: Replace `for_each` with `std::for_each`

Comment: @zeyuxie pls show your whole code, including _include_ statements

Comment: And avoid the `using namespace std`.

Comment: it built with VS2017 after adding some headers

Comment: Show the **entire** source file.

Answer (score 0):

This here built on VS2017, maybe you have forgot some header?

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void foo()
{
  using namespace std;
  map<string, int> M;
  vector<string> V;
  set<string> S;

  ifstream inFile("sample_doc.txt");
  copy(istream_iterator<string>(inFile), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(V));
  ifstream inFile2("stopwords.txt");
  copy(istream_iterator<string>(inFile2), istream_iterator<string>(), inserter(S, S.begin()));

  for_each(V.begin(), V.end(), [&](string & s) { S.count(s) == 0 ? M[s]++ : true; });
}
```